# How to Switch component in React like an app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-applications

I am a beginner in React, and I would like to make a web app with a dashboard like Windows tiles.
I generate them easily. But I want when I click in one of them, that hide the Dash menu and Display the sub-app "Prog1". And of course, reverse it. When I click the close button, it closes the sub-app and returns to the Dash menu (implying that it hides the Prog1 to display Dash).

I can hide the Dash menu with a function like this:

```
fctHide = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: false });
}
```

But how can I display the other subApp with maybe a function like fctShow?

Are we forced to put the function inside a class or just make a general display/hide function?
Is there an easier and newer way to do this (with hooks for example).

My app is on Codepen here : [codepen](https://codepen.io/lecybermax/pen/LYGgEjQ?editors=1010)
I can show you here on demand.

I'm surprised to see lots of questions or tutorials to show and hide elements from a button but not to switch between class/HTML/template etc. (like React Native router I guess).

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need react-router

Comment: We can't do this with the vanilla React ? Else, I don't understand the interest of it. ^^

Comment: Well, of course you could render conditionally in just one big component (i.e. you set state on button click and render accordingly), but 1. you'd be lost inside your own logic soon, 2. you'd get a freaking lot of code inside one component (against general programming practice of refactoring), 3. it'd be against React best practices, 4. `react-router` is exactly the tool for removing such boilerplate. In my opinion Router belongs to "vanilla React".

Comment: Effectively It's maybe what i need. And good point, it works with react native too ! :)
It will be included in Django project. Is there a prolbmem ?

Comment: I just saw that React Hooks are very similar to React Router and I could be good If I want to stay in the "vanilla branch" : https://blog.logrocket.com/how-react-hooks-can-replace-react-router/
But are hooks works on React Native if I wanna export the app to android for example. It's complicated to choose because I saw thats router works well with both React. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ! I finally use as proposed react-router. But I used the Hooks version (with <A>...)

So, the little dashboard is splitted in X parts :

- The HTML with only the minimum and root.
  `<div id="root"></div>`
- The CSS (nothing to say more)
- The sub apps in a specific folder "Apps"

```
import React from "react";
import { A } from "hookrouter";

class Prog1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="contProg1">
        <button class="close">
          {" "}
          <A href="/">Close</A>
        </button>
        <h1>Program 1</h1>
        <h2>Test1</h2>
        <h2>Test2</h2>
        <h2>Test3</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>AAAAA</li>
          <li>BBBBB</li>
          <li>CCCCC</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Prog1;
```

- The router page to switch between apps and main Dash.

```
import React from "react";
import Prog1 from "./Apps/Prog1";
import Prog2 from "./Apps/Prog2";
import Prog3 from "./Apps/Prog3";
import Prog4 from "./Apps/Prog4";
import Dash from "./App";

const routes = {
  "/": () => <Dash />,
  "/Prog1": () => <Prog1 />,
  "/Prog2": () => <Prog2 />,
  "/Prog3": () => <Prog3 />,
  "/Prog4": () => <Prog4 />
};

export default routes;
```

- The main page, the Dashboard (App.js).

```
import React from "react";
import { A } from "hookrouter";

const elements = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

function Dash() {
  const items = [];

  for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
    items.push(
      <A href={"/Prog" + (index + 1)}>
        <button key={index}>{value}</button>
      </A>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="Dash">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> {items} </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dash;
```

- And to finish, the Index page :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { useRoutes } from "hookrouter";
import routes from "./router";
import NoPageFound from "./Apps/404";

function App() {
  const routeResult = useRoutes(routes);
  return <div className="Dash">{routeResult || <NoPageFound />}</div>;
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

It works well. I just need to add something like MemoryRouter or something else to hide the URL and prepare for mobile version.
I'm just a little bit scared when I will insert this part in a Django project.
Or, maybe I should separate it ? (You don't need to answer, I will close I think).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are converting an old app to React, i.e. not writing a pure React app from the ground up, don't use ReactDOM.render multiple times. As you want to share the active state between components, it should live in their [closest common ancestor](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

I'm not sure how your dashboard should work, but here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-colden-ydzb3?file=/src/App.js). Here, APP is such closest ancestor. You don't need react-router if you are not using URL routes or the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Dash extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isActive, fctHide, fctShow } = this.props;
    const elements = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

    const items = [];

    for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
      items.push(
        <button
          key={index}
          onClick={() => {
            fctShow(index);
          }}
        >
          {value}
        </button>
      );
    }

    // if (isActive) {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td> {items} </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
    // } else {
    //   return null;
    // }
  }
}

class Prog1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isActive, selected, fctHide } = this.props;

    if (isActive) {
      return (
        <div className="contProg1">
          <button onClick={fctHide}>Close</button>
          <h1>Program 1</h1>
          <h2>Test1</h2>
          <h2>Test2</h2>
          <h2>Test3</h2>
          Selected: {selected}
          <ul>
            <li>AAAAA</li>
            <li>BBBBB</li>
            <li>CCCCC</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isActive: true, selected: null };
  }

  fctShow = selected => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true, selected });
  };

  fctHide = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { isActive, selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <Dash
          isActive={isActive}
          fctHide={this.fctHide}
          fctShow={this.fctShow}
        />
        <Prog1 isActive={isActive} selected={selected} fctHide={this.fctHide} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good works thanks.
Now we can open and close the sub app that's good. But, the most important is when i open the sub app, i hide the main 1/2/3/4 Dash.